# Getting strange error (unicodedecodeerror) installing any version of VMware esxi on dell r720 server

Tags: vmware, sd-card, esxi, dell-poweredge

m having an issue installing ESXi on the SD card on a dell r720.

The installer starts and prompts a quick CPU related error but progresses to the the install phase:

[image: cpu related error]

The install phase gets stuck at scanning devices:

[image: scanning devices]

I have tried ESXi 7 and 8.0.1 as well as the dell version of ESXi 8.0.1

The server previously had 8.0.0 installed with no issues.

Which was lost due to an attempt to rebuilding redundancy with the SD cards

I have tried to launch the setup bypassing the CPU checks, and have updated the firmware on the server.

based on troubleshooting it looks like the CPU is no longer supported, however, since 8.0.0 was working find, I suspect this is unrelated.

I'm going to run the hardware diags to see if there is a fault, but I wanted to post incase anyone had other ideas?

Comment: Does your hardware meet the requirements for the versions of ESXi you are trying to install?

Comment: no, the CPU is not of the supported list, however ESXi 7 and 8 have installed no problem in the past, so I'm not convinced that this is a compatibility issue.

Comment: These SD cards, you replaced the hardware?

Comment: yes and no the SD cards were setup to mirror each other, but some time ago one failed, It ran some time with the single card, this whole issue started after I replaced the card and attempted to rebuild the mirror. I think this ended up overwriting the working card causing the ESXI install to be deleted. The datastores were all on the disk array, so I am hoping all I need to do is to reinstall and configure ESXI and remount the datastore.

Comment: Update on this, turns out that this issue was related to the SD cards. I took them out and wiped them using the disk part clean option, and replaced them. I was then able to complete the Installation, I suspect that there was a portion of the previous VMware installation on one of the cards..

Answer (score 0):

Update on this, turns out that this issue was related to the SD cards. I took them out and wiped them using the disk part clean option, and replaced them. I was then able to complete the Installation, I suspect that there was a portion of the previous VMware installation on one of the cards..